# Basic program to determine digits in a number does not work with higher numbers?

Tags: java

I've made a little block of code that has the goal of attempting to store all the digits of a number into an array. For example, the number "123" would be stored as {1,2,3}. Everything seems to work fine, except for when the length of the number is larger then 10. Is it something wrong with my method? The exact error message is

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1202020202020202020"
>           at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
>           at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:652)
>           at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:770)
>           at test.main(test.java:8)

```
public class test {

public static void main(String[] args){

    //This block of code parses the zipcode and stores each number it has into an array. It also fetches the length, which is used later.
    String input = args[0];       
    int length = input.length();
    int zipcode = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    int[] digits = new int[length];         
    for(int i = 0; i < length ; i++){ 
        digits[i] = zipcode % 10; 
        zipcode = zipcode /10;
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Look closely at your error message: `For input string: "n"` ... you appear to be inputting text somehow.  I see nothing wrong with your logic, and it should work for a number string of arbitrary length.

Comment: I actually replaced that n with the number I was using to avoid confusion, but it appears I only achieved the opposite!. I'll change it back to what it was in the error message, which was "1202020202020202020"

Comment: Well that is larger than the maximum `int`, so you can't use `int` or `parseInt()`. You should just count the characters, which `.length()` already does, and make sure each one is numeric, if that's your requirement. It isn't in UK for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The largest number your code will handle is Integer.MAX_VALUE, which is 2147483647. Beyond that, you're trying to parse a number that won't fit in an Integer.  Using a Long will give you a lot more room.

Just saw @user207421's comment, and he/she is right...you really don't need to ever store your string as a numeric value.  If you had to, and wanted to handle very large numbers, you could use BigDecimal.

Also, per what you say you want, I think your final array is going to be in the reverse order of what you want.